# Getting Status of a usb printer on linux nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, escpos

I have just spent the last 3 days trawling the internet to get this to work.
I simply need to find the status of paper on a usb thermal printer under /dev/usb/lp0.

reducing my code to the mimimum for human consumption i have this:

```
const escpos = require('escpos');
escpos.USB = require('escpos-usb');
const device  = new escpos.USB();


const printer = new escpos.Printer(device);

device.open(function (err) {
    device.device.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.toString('hex'));
    });

    device.write(_.DLE);
    device.write(_.EOT);
    device.write(String.fromCharCode(1));

    setTimeout(() => {
        printer.close();
    }, 1000);
});
```

In response I get :

```
/root/totem/ser.js:9
    device.device.on('data', function (data) {
                  ^

TypeError: device.device.on is not a function
    at /root/totem/ser.js:9:19
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/escpos-usb/index.js:142:23)
    at Device.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/usb/usb.js:341:6)
```

Following suggestion of correcting

```
device.device.on
to 
device.on
```

I now get:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/totem# node ser.js
Received:


Received:


Received:


Received:
<Buffer >

root@raspberrypi:~/totem#
```

Instead of getting one byte that tells me the status

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> device.device

Use

device.on('data' ...

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected as suggested but still not working